# Create a synonym (or similar) for multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, synonym

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express. I want to create a synonym (or similar inline solution) to substitute in multiple standard column names across many tables.

For example, almost every table in my database has 3 identical columns: `ID`, `DateAdded` and `TenantID`. I want to have a way to select these without having to list them all out every time.

I tried some simple code as below to try to achieve this, but the syntax isn't correct in the create synonym section.  I've googled but can't find anything that gives me what I'm after as an inline solution.

So for example, rather than:

```sql
SELECT [ID], [DateAdded], [TenantID] 
FROM TableName
```

instead, I hoped to use this code to create a synonym:

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Fields] FOR [ID], [DateAdded], [TenantID]
```

then I can repeatedly write the query:

```sql
SELECT dbo.[Fields] FROM TableName
```

and have the `TableName` be different every time.

I need this to work across many tables, so creating a view for each table won't be satisfactory.

Maybe synonyms aren't the right solution, but if not then I'd be happy to hear of some other way that provides an inline solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the post for a while as the topic seems interesting and a learning opportunity to me :) Not sure this is possible or not, but you can think about Dynamic query execution as an alternative as below-

```
DECLARE @C_Names VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @T_Name VARCHER(MAX)

SET @C_Names = '[ID], [DateAdded], [TenantID]'
SET @T_Name = 'your_table_name'
--AS column names are fixed, you can now change the table name
--only and execute the script to get your desired output

EXEC('SELECT '+@C_Names+' FROM '+@T_Name+'')
```

Hope this will at least give you some light of hope.